# Dynamic class structure holding events for each day of the month

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have to represent JSON as class structures so I can use it to return those class in asp.net core endpoints. I need to return object holding each day of the current month and for every day holds array of events.

Here is the JSON, where numbers are day of the month.

```
[
  {
    "1":[
      {
        "Title":"Meeting",
        "DateTime":"12:40"
      },
      {
        "Title":"Launch",
        "DateTime":"13:30"
      }
    ],
    "2":[
      {
        "Title":"Test",
        "DateTime":"9:30"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is the code:

```
public class 1
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
}

public class 2
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
}

public class MonthEventsResponseModel
{
    public IList<1> 1 { get; set; }
    public IList<2> 2 { get; set; }
    // and so on to 31
}
```

So if there is a better solution for achieving this, I'm glad to know.

Comment: Despite the fact that `List<1> 1` won´t compile you should use a `List<List<Whatever>>`, as not every month has 31 days. Altrnativly also a jagged array However I´m not sure if that´s what you consider "better solution".

Comment: Call the class `Day` and have a property `DayOfMonth` which is 1 to (n) days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be,

1) Create enum for all month in year,

```
public enum Month
{
    NotSet = 0,
    January = 1,
    February = 2,
    March = 3,
    April = 4,
    May = 5,
    June = 6,
    July = 7,
    August = 8,
    September = 9,
    October = 10,
    November = 11,
    December = 12
}
```

2) Create one custom method that can take a month from above enum for a particular year,
and it calculates a number of days in a given month and for each of day you can fill your event data

```
public static MonthEventsResponseModel GetEventData(int year, Month month)
{
    var days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, (int)month);

    MonthEventsResponseModel model = new MonthEventsResponseModel();
    model.Events = Enumerable.Range(1, days)
        .Select(day => new
        {
            Day = day,
            Event = new List<Event>()  //<= Instead of new list, Fill Event data with respect to particular day from List or Database Call or API call
        })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Day, y => y.Event);

    return model;
}
```

3) Then call above method like,

```
MonthEventsResponseModel model = GetEventData(2018, Month.December);
```

4) Finally convert your model to json,

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
```

5) And class models are,

```
public class Event
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
}

public class MonthEventsResponseModel
{
    public Dictionary<int, List<Event>> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you man, actually I don't need to fill all days if there is no events for that day, but your solution was most helpfup so I will accept your answer for best. :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that will describe an event:

```
public class Event
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

And modify your `MonthEventsResponseModel` to this:

```
public class MonthEventsResponseModel
{
    public Dictionary<int, List<Event>> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialize your json with `DeserializeObject` method and some linq:

```
var json = "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"1\":[\r\n      {\r\n        \"Title\":\"Meeting\",\r\n        \"DateTime\":\"12:40\"\r\n      },\r\n      {\r\n        \"Title\":\"Launch\",\r\n        \"DateTime\":\"13:30\"\r\n      }\r\n    ],\r\n    \"2\":[\r\n      {\r\n        \"Title\":\"Test\",\r\n        \"DateTime\":\"9:30\"\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n]";

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Event[]>[]>(json)
    .Select(x => new MonthEventsResponseModel
    {
        Events = x.ToDictionary(k => int.Parse(k.Key), v => v.Value.ToList())
    }).ToArray();
```

Comment: I don't ned to Deserialize Objects, I need to Serialize them from class to JSON.

Comment: @IliyanIvanov Please show your actual data source from which you taking events.

Comment: I'm taking them from Event entity class with EF Core 2.2. dbContext.Event (that returns IQueryable<Event>)

Comment: @IliyanIvanov you need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54922552/edit) your question and add source code of that `Event` class

Comment: I solve my problem, thanks for trying to help me. The class structure I have needed was Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<Even>>

Answer (score 0):

I'd go ahead and make Event, Day, Month models, each responsible for serializing themselves -

Event

```
    public class Event
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string DateTime { get; set; }

        public string MakeJson()
        {

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            stringBuilder
                .Append("  {").AppendLine()
                .Append("    \"Title\":\"" + Meeting + "\",").AppendLine()
                .Append("    \"DateTime\":\"" + DateTime + "\"").AppendLine()
                .Append("  },").AppendLine();

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Day

```
    public class Day
    {
        public string DayNo { get; set; }
        public List<Event> Events { get; set; }

        public string MakeJson()
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            stringBuilder.Append("\"" + DayNo + "\":[").AppendLine();    

            foreach (Event ev in Events)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(ev.MakeJson());
            }

            stringBuilder.AppendLine().Append("],").AppendLine();

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Month

```
    public class Month{

        public List<Day> Days { get; set; }

        public string MakeJson()
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            stringBuilder.Append("[")
                .AppendLine().Append(" {")
                .AppendLine();

            foreach (Day day in Days)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(day.MakeJson());
            }

            stringBuilder.Append(" }")
                .AppendLine().Append("]")
                .AppendLine();


        }
    }
```

Once you populate the models just call MakeJson() on the month and you're good to go.